# How to change negative Y axis domain to be positive

Tags: javascript, css, d3.js

I have this code:

```
y.domain([-arr2, arr2]).nice();

svg.append("g")
   .attr("class", "y axis")
   .call(yAxis)
   .append("text")
   .attr("class", "label")
   .attr("transform", "rotate(-90)")
   .attr("x", 150)
   .attr("y", -10)
   .attr("dy", ".71em")
   .style("text-anchor", "end")
   .attr("font-family", "sans-serif")
   .attr("font-size", "34px")
   .text("log(Lev)");
```

This is the graph with Y axis created by this code:

[image]

As you can see, Y axis have a negative portion (0 <--> -25) bellow X axis, 
i whould like to change negative Y axis domain to be positive.

So i get something like:

[image]

Comment: because i want to show temporal differences between multi line paths, and i have two different sets of line paths. That is why i choose to create a varianced mirroring.

Comment: You want to use a custom render for the axis labels. You can do it with `yAxis.tickFormat(function(v){ return String(Math.abs(v)); })` (https://github.com/mbostock/d3/wiki/SVG-Axes#wiki-tickFormat)

Comment: It's working! How do I confirm that your answer is correct ? There is no V sign.

Comment: The "V" sign is a tick, and there isn't one because Prusse hasn't (yet) posted this as an answer.

Answer (score 1):

You can use:

```
yAxis = Math.abs(yAxis);
```

Comment: Ok you edited the question, now I don't know if this applies any more (not sure what you're asking now)

Comment: I just cut all the irrelevant picture. I need all values in Y axis to be positive, below X axis and above.

Comment: I know, but in doing so it removed context. It's now not so obvious what we're looking at. Either way, this will convert negative values to their positive counterparts. :)

Answer (score 0):

You want to use a custom render for the axis labels. You can do it with yAxis.tickFormat(function(v){ return String(Math.abs(v)); }) ([github.com/mbostock/d3/wiki/SVG-Axes#wiki-tickFormat](http://github.com/mbostock/d3/wiki/SVG-Axes#wiki-tickFormat)) –  Prusse 10 mins ago